# Sending PFUsers images from Parse

Tags: ios, image, file, parse-platform

This is the last thing I need to develop my client based app but have seriously hit a hard rock.

I am trying to send Users images directly from Parse and have a handful of images displayed to them.  What is the best way to go about this? I already have a User Login & Registration completely set up.  I also have a UIViewController filed as ConceptPage and a PFImageView filed as Concept1.

Ideally I would like to have these images stored in the "User" Class by adding "File" Columns. I've already went ahead and made one file column called "concept1"

Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point considering I'm now 2 weeks in of research on this topic.

Comment: Punctuation is key. Are you trying to send users? or images? or images that belong to users? or send images TO users? etc... Also, what code have you tried?

Comment: I am attempting to send images to users.

Comment: I truly appreciate you following up with me.  Unfortunately I am unsure as to how this applies to my app. I don't need the user to access their camera and I don't need them to save any images.  I want to be able to send a maximum of 3 photos to specific users. @JoeBlow

Comment: The class name is "UserPhoto" I have a file column named "imageFile" and a Pointer<_User> column named "user".

I want the user to tap a button to have a new ViewController up and automatically display a file that I stored in Parse using the UserPhoto-imageFile-Pointer<_User> info.

I am going to be storing the "imageFile" names under "Image.jpg"

@JoeBlow  I hope this better explains what I am trying to do.